# injecting value into html using innerHTML returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So basically im trying to inject information that comes from my database (im using postgresSQL and node.js) into the webpage and i have confirmed that im getting the information i want right before trying to innerHTML however as soon as it goes to that codeline somehow it can't detect the value and inject undefined (i think) and im not sure why it's doing that.

here is the javascript for the html page im having problems :

```
window.onload = async function() {

    try {
        let courseId = sessionStorage.getItem("courseId");
        let course = await $.ajax({
            url: `/api/courses/${courseId}/classes`,
            method: "get",
            dataType: "json"
        });

        document.getElementById("course").innerHTML = course.cour_name;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I find it really weird since i have done it similarly with another page and it works fine.

here is the html for the page:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Express</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/courses.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js%22%3E</script>
  <script src = "./javascript/courseInfo.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header id = "header">
    </header>
    <nav>
      <a href= "courses.html"><p>Back</p></a>
    </nav>
   <section>
     <main id="course">

     </main>
   </section>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't know why fills that field with undefined since when i stringify what the ajax return it shows that it has exactly what i need, one of those fields being the cour_name row.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me with this problem and thank you for your time.

Comment: my professor has an example using it like this so i tried the same thing but it's not working. i used it similarly like this as well when injecting into another page and it worked fine.

Comment: Should `course.cour_name` be `course.course_name`? What does `console.log(course)` reveal?

Comment: `sessionStorage` is temporary. Check it using `console.log(JSON.parse("courseId"))`

Comment: @JonP the row is named cour_name, i tried doing console log but for some reason it didn't go through, however i tried with alert and that one reveals [objectHTMLElement]

Comment: @zer00ne for some reason console.log aren't being read however when i try alert(courseId) it return the correct value.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an error? The script tag including the jQuery library isn't correct.

Comment: @gre_gor im not getting any errors, i injecting similarly like this in a page in the same folder and it worked with no problems. The only problem im getting is the one in the post.

Comment: Based on your screenshot in a comment below, `course` is an array with one element, what you want is `course[0].cour_name`

Comment: @Saikaro I screwed up that line try: `console.log(sessionStorage.getItem(JSON.parse("courseId")));`

Comment: @JonP You're right it was an array, changing to that line makes it work now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if using chrome browser , try devtool debugger.

open the DevTool (e.g. press F12) then click on sources tab and locate your javascript file and put a breakpoint on the line this not working as expected. then reload the page and check the value of variables and executes the rest of the code line by line.

see this tutorial on how to use debugger https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/

Comment: I just finished using the debugger and the value of the variable is exactly what i need, however the injection is undefined. If you need here's a print of it https://prnt.sc/26iwslx

Comment: @Saikaro, actually it isn't exactly what you need, it is an array. See my comment above.

Comment: before giving negative point to my comment check the debugger more carefully.
your course variable shows an array with one object inside it. so the you need to access what you want using course[0].cour_name

Comment: document.getElementById("course").innerHTML = course[0].cour_name;

Comment: @pref thank you, now it's working it was an array, also i wasn't the one who gave you a negative point just to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Good luck